# i coud not read total rows some rows is jumbed

Tags: java, android

i need to debug the below code to trace some unexpected results from the begining of the while loop. i put break point in the line of while loop but the debugger does not reach to it i want the debugger to run all code before that line then stop at the line to be debugged step by step how can i do that
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button readExcelButton;
static String TAG = "ExelLog";
ArrayList<PhoneData> phoneData = new ArrayList<PhoneData>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}


public void readFile(View view) {

    if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Storage not available or read only");
        return;
    }

    try {
```

// Creating Input Stream

```
        File file = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "3.xls");
        // FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStream inStream;
        Workbook wb = null;
        inStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

// Create a workbook using the File System

```
        wb = new HSSFWorkbook(inStream);
```

// Get the first sheet from workbook
Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

```
        int totalNumberOfRows = sheet1.getLastRowNum();
        Log.d(TAG, "RowsNo: " + totalNumberOfRows);

        int i = 6;
        while (i <= totalNumberOfRows) {

            if (sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(16).getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {


                double duration = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(16).getNumericCellValue();
                if (duration > .91 && duration < 1) {
                    //sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(8).setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
                    double status = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(8).getNumericCellValue();

                    if (status == 60 || status == 72 || status == 73 || status == 101) {
                        System.out.println("if succeed");

                        Double telephone = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(2).getNumericCellValue();
                        int tel = telephone.intValue();
                        System.out.println("telephone is" + tel);
                    }
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "Telephone Number: " + Double.toString(telephone), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //   String exchange = sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
                    //   String complainTime =sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(5).getStringCellValue();
                    //   phoneData.add(new PhoneData(Double.toString(telephone), exchange,Double.toString(status),complainTime));
                    //   System.out.println("exchange is"+exchange + duration+status+complainTime );

                }


                System.out.println("Test Data From Excel" + duration);
                System.out.println("Row Number" + i);


            } else {
                System.out.println("Not Numeric");
            }
            i++;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return;


}


private static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() {
    String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
    String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

}

Comment: I can't see the problem from the code, suggest you run it in debugging mode and follow line by line to identify the points where it seems to be skipping a line.  Hopefully something will stand out as unexpected!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and several variable declarations. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].